# See if a user exists at a firebase location

Tags: javascript, firebase

What is a way to check if a user exists at a firebase location?  Would you use `.child()` somehow? A variable would store the user name entered:

user name:

```
var user = "test";
```

firebase returned object:

```
snapshot { '
   -JruhOP3M496hEAKn6': 
   { 
      email: 'chaselester.cl@gmail.com',
      password: 'kimberlyn#1',
      username: 'chipe' 
   },
  '-Ju8J72xo3UpSIwEYw': { 
      email: 'test', 
      password: 'test', 
      username: 'test' },
  '-Ju8J9m_DC18irjWep': { 
      email: 'one', 
      password: 'three', 
      username: 'two' 
  } 
}
```

### Update: code from comment

It seems if the user does not exist `firebaseRef.push` calls `firebaseRef.orderByChild` and the whole function runs again because in the log it logs "User does not exist" then right after it logs "User Exists" and my res.json is called twice and I get an app crash with the comment "Can't set headers after they are sent". How can I push to firebase if the user does not exist without having it re evaluate the `firebaseRef.orderByChild`?

Here is the full function I am doing in my server.js:

```
firebaseRef.orderByChild('username').equalTo(user).on('value', function(snapshot) { 
  if (snapshot.hasChildren()) { 
    console.log('User exists'); 
    res.json(true); 
  }else if(!snapshot.hasChildren()){ 
    console.log('User does not exist'); 
    firebaseRef.push(req.body); 
    res.json(false); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: `ref.orderByChild('username').equalTo(user).on('value', function(snapshot) { if (snapshot.hasChildren()) { console.log('User exists'); })`

Comment: Awesome, that works. I am in the server part of my node.js app, and when I want to add the user to firebase if they are not set I get "Can't set headers after they are set. Here is my code: if (snapshot.hasChildren()) { 
            console.log('User exists');
            res.json(true); 
        }else if(!snapshot.hasChildren()){
            console.log('User does not exist');
            firebaseRef.push(req.body);
            res.json(false);
        }

When I look at the console logs I see logged "user does not exist" and the next line right after I see "user exists" any clue?

Comment: Here is the full function I am doing in my server.js:

firebaseRef.orderByChild('username').equalTo(user).on('value', function(snapshot) { 
        if (snapshot.hasChildren()) { 
            console.log('User exists');
            res.json(true); 
        }else if(!snapshot.hasChildren()){
            console.log('User does not exist');
            firebaseRef.push(req.body);
            res.json(false);
        }
    });

Its like the firebaseRef.push is calling the firebaseRef.orderByChild again

Comment: Please don't post significant code in comments. Instead click the *edit* link under your question and add it there next time.

Comment: The `on` callback will remain registered, so as soon as you create the user it will fire again. You may want a `once` callback in this case.

Comment: That `once` is the answer to your last question. But note that we've now gone from "how can I check of a user exists?" to "how can I ensure that a callback runs only once?". StackOverflow really appreciates a "one question per question" approach.

Comment: Gotcha, I will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: You're welcome. I realized straight away this had been asked before, which is why I only commented. I might still mark as a duplicate once I find a dupe.